# Size is not unloading from Caffeine caches

Tags: java, caffeine

Right now i just wondering why, prob need help also.

So when i add values to my list it will be added but after 5 min it will remove, that works
But if i do list.size() it still says 1 but there is no values inside

```
public class Test extends Runnable {

   private ExpiringSet<User> users; //User is just my object class 

   public Test() {
       users  = new ExpiringSet<User>(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); //Sets the users

       users.add(new User("John"));
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       // This will always say 1 even after i wait 1hour ive seen it has increased after a while then it said 2 
       //and there is no values in the users
       System.out.println("Size: " + users.size()); 

       //But this is empty after 5min        
       for(Iterator<User> iter = users.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
           User user = (User)iter.next();
           System.out.println("User " + user.getName());
       }
   }

}

public class ExpiringSet<E> extends ForwardingSet<E> {
   private final Set<E> setView;

   public ExpiringSet(long duration, TimeUnit unit) {
       Cache<E, Boolean> cache = CaffeineFactory.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(duration, unit).build();
       this.setView = Collections.newSetFromMap(cache.asMap());
   }

   @Override
   protected Set<E> delegate() {
       return this.setView;
   }
}
```

Basically i just want the users.size() to be 0 if there is no values inside users.
It just seems weird when it says 1 and there is no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default expired entries are removed lazily during routine maintenance, which is triggered by a few reads or a write. That results in size of the underlying map being exposed, whereas the entries will be hidden if queried for and evicted at some later point. The `Cache.cleanUp()` can be called to run the maintenance work.

A background thread is required if you want expired entries to be removed promptly regardless of cache activity. This can be configured by configuring a `Scheduler` on the builder. Java 9+ includes a built-in JVM-wide scheduling thread rather than spinning up a new one, so the cache can be configured as,

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .scheduler(Scheduler.systemScheduler())
    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key));
```

Comment: The Cache.cleanUp() did it for me